# Bootstrap Carousel is not working with dynamic images via variable

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to get a carousel with variable, in which data is fetch from XML url, no issue in images; we are fetching the data successfully, but the carousel is not working with them.

```js
// Populate the carousel with car images
const carouselImages = document.getElementById('carouselImages');


carData.imageURLs.forEach((imageUrl, index) => {
  const item = document.createElement('div');
  item.classList.add("carousel-item");
  // item.className = `carousel-item ${index === 0 ? 'active' : ''}`;
  if (index === 0) {
    item.classList.add("active"); // Set the first item as active
  }
  const image = document.createElement('img');
  image.src = imageUrl;
  image.className = 'd-block w-100';
  image.alt = carData.title;

  item.appendChild(image);
  carouselImages.appendChild(item);
});
}
else {
  // Handle the case where the car with the specified ID was not found
  console.error('Car not found.');
}
```

```html
<!-- Car images and details to match SweetAlert2 popup -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <!-- Carousel for car images -->
    <div id="popupCarousel" class="carousel slide popup-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner" id="carouselImages">
        <!-- Carousel items will be populated dynamically here -->
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#popupCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#popupCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

only the first image is visible

Comment: I tried to make a snippet of your code but it is not properly formed here

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create a carousel of images from data fetched from an XML URL, but only the first image is visible. The issue you're facing might be related to the initialization of the Bootstrap Carousel component. You need to make sure the Bootstrap Carousel is properly initialized after adding the items dynamically. Here's a modified version of your code to ensure that the carousel works correctly:

```js
// Assuming you have fetched your data and stored it in carData as an array of image URLs.

const carouselImages = document.getElementById('carouselImages');

// Iterate through carData to populate the carousel
carData.forEach((imageUrl, index) => {
    const item = document.createElement('div');
    item.classList.add("carousel-item");

    if (index === 0) {
        item.classList.add("active"); // Set the first item as active
    }

    const image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = imageUrl;
    image.className = 'd-block w-100';
    image.alt = 'Car Image'; // You can set a common alt text here

    item.appendChild(image);
    carouselImages.appendChild(item);
});

// Initialize the Bootstrap Carousel
$('#popupCarousel').carousel();
```

In this modified code:

Iterate through carData, assuming it's an array of image URLs.

Create and append the carousel items and images dynamically.

After adding all the items, initialize the Bootstrap Carousel manually using `$('#popupCarousel').carousel();`. This ensures that the carousel is correctly set up after the items have been added dynamically.